# Python: how to parse a file and finding missing data per column?

Tags: python

I will do my best to try to explain my question:

I'm writing a python script and I stacked at some point. I have the following table/matrix:

```
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
```

The data follows the following pattern; "x" is a number that change but the letters are constant in the same order and in pairs per column. What I want to do is to introduce a  where the data is missing, getting the following output:

```
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx **<NA>**    xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx xx_rd_xx xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
Data xx_a_xx xx_a_xx xx_b_xx xx_b_xx **<NA>**     xx_rd_xx xx_c_xx xx_c_xx
```

Any type or advice? Thanks

Comment: I think my answer is concise, and the question is ok, so please, @jonrsharpe and further holders, reconsider the flagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first `split` the row strings by the space character;
then you'd throw away the "Data" word.

You could then convert your "xx_a_xx" type strings to tuples, let's say you write a function `string_to_key` that maps "99_a_72" to "a"; you map that function to the list.

Afterwards, you just check whether the things are in right order, and pad with the N/A values if they're not.

```
....
def string_to_key(string):
    return string.split("_")[1] #will produce an exception on malformed lines!
....
reference = ("a","a","b","b","rd","rd","c","c")

for row in rows: #assuming rows is the result of reading all lines
    items = row.split(" ")[1:] #throwing away "Data"
    keys = [string_to_key(string) for string in items]
    result = []
    for num, ref_key in enumerate(reference):
         if keys[num] == ref_key:
              result.append(items[num])
         else:
              result.append("**NA**")
              keys.insert("")
    print "Data "+" ".join(result)
```